# How to know if a value matches one value or another but not both SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

*Hey*, I have a question regarding an "xor" in SQL

I need to know if a value if one column matches one of the two given values but not both, for example, need to return the names of those who match Dollar or Euro, **but not both**, they can match other currencies.

```
Name | Currency
---------------
John | Dollar
John | Euro
John | Dollar
Peter| Euro
Peter| Pound
Bob  | Dollar
```

In this example I need to return both Peter and Bob.
I have tried symmetric difference, the union of those who have dollars and euros minus the intersection, but it is a big chunk of code and not working properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is one way , using group by :

```
SELECT * 
FROM curenncyname  c1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT name , Currency, COUNT(*) 
        FROM urenncyname c2
        WHERE c2.name = c1.name 
        GROUP BY name , Currency
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT name
FROM t
WHERE currency IN ('Dollar', 'Euro')
GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(currency) = MAX(currency);
```

Of, if you like, you can use set operators:

```
select name
from t
where currency in ('Dollar', 'Euro')
minus
(select name
 from t
 where currency in ('Dollar')
 intersect
 select name
 from t
 where currency in ('Euro')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use it is to use a FULL JOIN with an appropriate filter in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COALESCE(d.NAME, e.NAME)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE CURRENCY = 'Dollar') d
  FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE CURRENCY = 'Euro') e
    ON e.Name = d.Name
  WHERE (e.Name IS NULL     AND d.Name IS NOT NULL) OR
        (e.Name IS NOT NULL AND d.Name IS NULL)
```

This returns

```
Peter
Bob
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=122fd8f982c1763ffb0582aaff8d158e)